# Статус фразы "это не есть хорошо"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Часто сталкиваюсь с такой фразой: **это не есть хорошо** (вместо "это нехорошо" или "это плохо").
Что же это: словесный недуг или порок?

Answer (score 2):

Это давно и постепенно проникало в русский язык. Вероятно как ироничное подражание разговору иностранцев. В литературе с начала прошлого века можно встретить это выражение (обычно с отсылкой на немцев). Подтверждающие цитаты и интересное обсуждение можно найти [на этой странице жж](https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4787575.html?page=2).

Перенесу на всякий случай сюда некоторые цитаты, приведенные жж-пользователем **kcmamu**:

> ...Людвиг Карлович помахал толстым пальцем перед носом зама и еще раз повторил: — Это не есть правильно. После ухода Злотиса он долго шагал по кабинету. Потом вызвал Гарпинского. Усадив его в кресло, откупорил свежую бутылку, налил два бокала и, взяв один, чокнулся. — Не надо ссориться. Это не есть хорошо. Надо работать... (А. Бибик, 1927)
>
> ...Серб, это не есть хорошо! — вставил первый судья и нахмурился. — Сербской веры, не есть, не есть хорошо! Это пахнет порохом!.. (Петар Кочич, перевод М. Волконского, 1960; дело происходит в австрийском суде в Боснии, судья — немец)
>
> ...Каждый из нас норовит поиграть другим, что не есть хорошо, как говорят мои немецкие друзья... (Ю. Семенов, 1984)
>
> ...Это не есть хорошо, как говорят немцы, но это еще полбеды... (С. Шуртаков, 1986)